# How to flatten object values to a 1D array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
const obj = {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6]}
```

I expect to get array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

here is function that i used but it give me only the last array:  `[4, 5, 6]`

```
for (const property in obj) {
    var allData = []
    allData.push(...obj[property])
}
```

Comment: You're redeclaring `allData` on each iteration. Move `var allData = []` outside (before) the loop.

Comment: If the structure of `obj` is known and fixed then I would go for something simple like `allData = [...obj.a, ...obj.b]`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare the var outside the loop

```js
const obj = {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6]};
var allData = [];
for (const property in obj) {    
    allData.push(...obj[property])
}
console.log(allData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring allData in each loop iteration.

```js
const obj = {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6]};

const allData = Object.values(obj).reduce((initial, val) => {
    initial.push(...val);
    return initial;
}, []);

console.log(allData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the values from the object and merge them together using `reduce`. Use the below code:

```js
const obj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6] }

const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current], [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: just `Object.values(obj).flat()`

Answer (score 1):

For Node.js 11+ and the browser versions released during the last 2-4 years you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to produce the desired outcome like this:

```js
const obj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6] };

const allData = Object.values(obj).flat();

console.log(allData);
```